# jqLite: elm.css("width") is returning an empty string

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

This appears to be an issue with jqLite, which I came across while working with angular.js.  To see the problem, open the console tab and click "run with js" in [this jsbin](http://jsbin.com/owiher/2/edit).  `left.css("width")` is returning an empty string when it shouldn't be.

#### HTML

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app>
  <head>
<meta name="description" content="Angular Template" />
    <script src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.0.6/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="left"><span id="test">left</span></div>
      <div class="right">right</div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

#### CSS

```
.container {display:table; width:100%;}
.left {border: 1px dashed purple; display:table-cell; overflow:hidden; width: 66%; height: 20px;}
.right {display:table-cell; background:green;  width: 34%; height: 20px;}
```

#### JS

```
var innerSpan = document.getElementById("test");
var left = angular.element(innerSpan);
console.log(left.css("width"));
```

When I inspect the element using the chrome dev tools panel, the computed width is definitely not the  empty string?  What am I missing here?

Comment: Did you try just `innerSpan.style.width` ?

Comment: Well, I specifically want to know *why* this isn't working, but in any case that idea doesn't work either.  You get `Cannot read property 'width' of undefined`

Comment: Oh, you placed the javascript code before the elements, so when getting `document.getElementById("test")` that element does'nt exist yet, that's why jQuery has document ready.

Comment: you need to add jQuery

Comment: why do you need to add jQuery?

Comment: you definitely do not need to add jQuery

Comment: @adeneo, that doesn't appear to help either.  See: http://jsbin.com/itorib/2/edit

Comment: @AbrahamUribe, that is not the problem, as others have pointed out.  angular includes a subset of jquery called jqLite, which is what I'm using here.

Comment: @Langdon, did you see my last link in the comments?  Why didn't that fix it?  Or if you want just answer with a working jsbin.

Comment: The test element has no width, but the parent has? If no width is applied, you can't get it either ?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can't use `.css('width')` to get the width of an element.  You use it to get the styled width.  Since you didn't define the width in the element's style attribute, you get no value.

Try `.prop('offsetWidth')` instead.

Also, when using jsbin.com, your script is automatically included.  Including script.js is just throwing a 404.

Comment: Langdon, you magnificent bastard!